# How to get RabbitMQ management command line tool to work on Windows

Tags: windows-8, rabbitmq

I've followed the instructions [RabbitMQ management command line tool](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html) but when running with

```
python.exe rabbitmqadmin.exe
```

Gives me an error:

```
ERROR: Action not specified
```

and:

```
rabbitmqadmin --help
```

displays:

[image]

Is this really the case or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't rename rabbitmqadmin to rabbitmqadmin.exe - it's really not an executable file. That is the cause of the (remarkably misleading) "cannot start due to incompatibility" message you're seeing.

```
ERROR: Action not specified
```

is due to... not specifying an action.

But the bit you might be missing is that on Windows you **always** need to prefix invocations with python.exe e.g.:

```
python.exe rabbitmqadmin --help
python.exe rabbitmqadmin declare exchange name=my-exchange type=topic
```

Answer (score 7):

The error means exactly what it says, you didn't invoke rabbitmqadmin correctly by specifying a command.

### **Walkthough on how to use rabbitmqadmin:**

For me the executable is called: `rabbitmqadmin` downloaded from here: 
https://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html

**Executing it from commandline without any options, and you get an error:**

```
eric@dev ~$ python rabbitmqadmin
ERROR: Action not specified
rabbitmqadmin --help for help
```

**Getting help on generic options:**

```
eric@dev ~$ python rabbitmqadmin --help
<prints a mountain of help>
```

**Get a list of subcommands you can run:**

```
python rabbitmqadmin help subcommands
```

**Get a list of users:**

```
eric@dev ~$ python rabbitmqadmin list users
+-------+------------------------------+---------------+
| name  |        password_hash         |     tags      |
+-------+------------------------------+---------------+
| guest | oiz5zGozWya1qBblv6gbFrGYCnA= | administrator |
+-------+------------------------------+---------------+
```

**List vhosts:**

```
eric@dev ~$ python rabbitmqadmin list vhosts
+------+----------+----------------+-------------------------+----------+----------+---------+
| name | messages | messages_ready | messages_unacknowledged | recv_oct | send_oct | tracing |
+------+----------+----------------+-------------------------+----------+----------+---------+
| /    | 0        | 0              | 0                       | 1218     | 1028     | False   |
| foo  |          |                |                         |          |          | False   |
+------+----------+----------------+-------------------------+----------+----------+---------+
```

**List Exchanges:**

```
eric@dev ~$ python rabbitmqadmin list exchanges
+-------+--------------------+---------+-------------+---------+----------+
| vhost |        name        |  type   | auto_delete | durable | internal |
+-------+--------------------+---------+-------------+---------+----------+
| /     |                    | direct  | False       | True    | False    |
| /     | amq.direct         | direct  | False       | True    | False    |
| /     | amq.fanout         | fanout  | False       | True    | False    |
| /     | amq.headers        | headers | False       | True    | False    |
| /     | amq.match          | headers | False       | True    | False    |
| /     | amq.rabbitmq.log   | topic   | False       | True    | False    |
| /     | amq.rabbitmq.trace | topic   | False       | True    | False    |
| /     | amq.topic          | topic   | False       | True    | False    |
| /     | logs               | fanout  | False       | False   | False    |
| /     | my-exchange        | topic   | False       | True    | False    |
+-------+--------------------+---------+-------------+---------+----------+
```

**Login as default user and get nodes:**

```
python rabbitmqadmin --username=guest --password=guest list nodes

<prints mountain of information about nodes>
```

**Login as guest and List Queues:**

```
eric@dev ~$ python rabbitmqadmin --username=guest --password=guest list queues
+-------+--------------------------------+-------------+-----------+---------+------------------------+---------------------+--------+----------+----------------+-------------------------+---------------------+--------+---------+
| vhost |              name              | auto_delete | consumers | durable | exclusive_consumer_tag |     idle_since      | memory | messages | messages_ready | messages_unacknowledged |        node         | policy | status  |
+-------+--------------------------------+-------------+-----------+---------+------------------------+---------------------+--------+----------+----------------+-------------------------+---------------------+--------+---------+
| /     | amq.gen-hWC6xdjX3g5GABc2nED-YQ | True        | 1         | False   |                        | 2014-09-08 13:24:34 | 14048  | 0        | 0              | 0                       | rabbit@ip-15-1-5-54 |        | running |
+-------+--------------------------------+-------------+-----------+---------+------------------------+---------------------+--------+----------+----------------+-------------------------+---------------------+--------+---------+
```